# Close blockquote by hitting enter twice

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Is there a way for blockquotes to close when hitting enter twice (just like lists do)?

I've seen these done in some places, but cant figure out why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will close the `blockquote`when you hit enter on an empty line. It will close other blocks too as fare as I know if line is empty when you hit return.

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        end_container_on_empty_block: true,
```

Comment: wow amazing!! thank you so much!!! But where is this line from? I can't locate it in the documentation!!!

thanks again mate :D

Comment: Also, any clue on why it's not closing <pre> elements?

Comment: I found this in a sample at http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/html5_formats.php It dosen't seam to work on pre-tags for the moment. TinyMce 4.x is rather new and this may not be implementet yet. Got no other explanation.

Comment: I understand, thanks! Can I ask you another TinyMce related question? Do you have an email I can use? Thanks :)

Comment: No prob. I'm no expert, but learning fast :) There is an email link on my site - which you find in my stackoverflow profile.